# I need to create number of guesses limit to 3, so how do I create that? feedback appreciated

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, while-loop, python-requests

I need help to create a guess limit.. I am struggling please advise and please leave feedback

...

```
from time import sleep
import random

sleep(2)

print("""
This program will generate a
guessing number for the user
to figure out. User has three
guesses before he loses.
Each number guessed right
he earns a point.
""")


num_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]


def user_pc_guess():
pc_number = random.randint(1, 20)
points = 0
num_guess = 0
num_limit = 3
out_of_limit = False
print("Points: "+str(points))
print("Guess: "+str(num_guess))
print("PC is grabbing a number...")
print(pc_number)
sleep(2)
out_of_limit = False
user_guess = ""

while num_guess < 3:
    user_guess = int(input("Guess a lucky number: "))
    if user_guess == pc_number:
        print("You've won a point!")
        if True:
            points += 1
            num_guess += 1
            print(points)
            question = input("Would you like to guess again? Enter Y or N: ").upper()
            if question == "Y":
                num_guess += 1
            else:
                print("Okay, Next Time!")
    elif user_guess == pc_number + 1 or user_guess == pc_number - 1 and pc_number in range(1, 21):
        print("You are very close!")
        num_guess += 1
    elif user_guess == pc_number + 2 or user_guess == pc_number - 2 and pc_number in range(1,21):
        print("Warm")
        num_guess += 1
    elif user_guess == pc_number + 3 or user_guess == pc_number - 3 and pc_number in range(1,21):
        print("Cold")
        num_guess += 1
    else:

        print("Lose")


user_pc_guess()
...
```

Comment: Firstly, don't state you're a beginner, include a signature, or say "thanks" in the question; all of those things are pure fluff that don't change the answer in any way. Secondly, which version of Python are you actually using? (you've tagged the question with both [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x]). Thirdly, does your code actually work as you expect? You wrote "I am struggling" but didn't specify what is wrong with the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Here a sample code for guess number, maybe good one. : )

```
import random
from time import sleep

def user_pc_guess(lower, upper, num_guess=3):
    global score
    print(f"Score: {score}")
    print("PC is grabbing a number...")
    sleep(1)
    pc_number = random.randint(lower, upper)
    message = {1:"You are very close!", 2:"Warm !", 3:"Cold !"}
    for i in range(num_guess):
        prompt = f"Guess #{i+1}/{num_guess} a lucky number in range ({lower}, {upper}): "
        user_guess = int(input(prompt))
        delta = abs(user_guess - pc_number)
        if lower <= user_guess <= upper:
            if delta == 0:
                print("Got it, you've won a point!")
                score += 1
                print(f'Score: {score}')
                break
            elif delta in message:
                print(message[delta])
            else:
                print("Lose !")
        else:
            print('Out of range and lose !')

message = """
This program will generate a guessing number for the user to figure out.
User has three guesses before he loses.
Each number guessed right he earns a point.
"""
print(message)

score = 0
while True:
    user_pc_guess(1, 10)
    print()
    question = input("Would you like to guess again? Enter Y or N: ").upper()
    if question == "Y":
        continue
    else:
        print("Okay, Next Time!")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the part of the code that caused the bug:

```
    else:
        print("Lose")
```

You see, if none of the above conditions meet, the `else` statement will be triggered, and you didn't add to `guess_num` there.